# Uploading 1.5 MB image as base 64 encoded data via POST parameter

Tags: php, post

I am trying to upload image of about 1.5 MB weight as base 64 encoded data via POST parameter.
But I am getting blank page as reponse after uploading data.

I have set these 2 PHP config properties.

```
ini_set("post_max_size", '20M');
ini_set("memory_limit ", '128M');
```

But no success!

Comment: Well, the receiving page probably has a lot to do with it.

Comment: Turn on error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors');`), also, share your upload code please, since I really don't understand what you mean by *upload as base 64 encoded data*.

Comment: I am using this code:

$data = $_POST['image_data'];
...Code to write base64_decoded data to file...

Comment: Can you show abit code of the uploading / recieving progress?

Comment: Also I turned on errors but errors received.

Comment: Here is the code:     

file_put_contents($dir.'/'.$filename, base64_decode($data));

Comment: what about the upload_max_filesize?